# search and replace multiple substrings in pandas

Tags: pandas, search, replace, substring

```
df = pd.read_csv('ProvidersImpressions.csv')   

searchfor = ['ACS','Kardiogener','tachykarde','bradykarde','PM/ICD','Lungenödem','hypertensiver','Aortenaneurysma','Hypotonie','Synkope','Thrombose','Lungenembolie','Herz']

df_cardiovascular = df[df['InjuryDetail'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor),na=False)]
```

[image: Dataframe after searching]

Above code give me a dataframe where InjuryDetail column contains string with substring that matches the substring of searchfor list.

But I would like to replace the strings with the substring that are matched with searchfor list like below image.

[image: Dataframe that I would like]

Comment: Try [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) instead of `str.contains` if you just want to have the element in searchfor if it is a substring in that column.

Comment: @Rabinzel   I get this error....... ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups.  My code is  df_cardiovascular = df[df['InjuryDetail'].str.extract('|'.join(searchfor))]

Comment: I posted an answer that should solve it. Little advice for the future, if you are posting a question, add a sample of the data as text to your question instead of an image. I couldn't reproduce your problem, hence couldn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to to replace the string in that column with the substring and also filter the df by it if there is no match.
This should solve it:

About your error mentioned in the comments: we just create the captured group by putting `()` around the joined searchfor list.

```
pattern = '(' + '|'.join(searchfor) + ')'
df['InjuryDetail'] = df['InjuryDetail'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
df_cardiovascular = df.dropna(subset='InjuryDetail')
```